# Angular-fullstack: PostgreSQL DB created, but can't get data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, postgresql, angular-fullstack

I am new to angularjs and I am trying to setup a first project with generator-angular-fullstack using yeoman and PostgreSQL. Everything seems working.

When I use grunt on localhost (grunt serve), I see a basic yeoman page, but no data. A database and tables are created. There is some test data. It looks like the conection from the project to the DB is working, but it can't access the data.

DB config in development.js:

```
module.exports = {
  // MongoDB connection options
  mongo: {
    uri: 'mongodb://localhost/fullstack-dev'
 },

  // Postgres connection options
  postgres: {
          uri: process.env.POSTGRES_URL ||
         'postgres://user:pass@localhost:5432/testDB'
  },
  database: 'testDB',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'postgres',
  seedDB: true
  };
```

screens
[pgadmin DB screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxW1R.png)
[index.html screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWOpw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figured it out, it is bug/mistake in index.html code

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1 class="page-header">Features:</h1>

       <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="thing in awesomeThings">

    <li><a href="#" tooltip="{{thing.info}}">{{thing.name}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But Select from DB is

```
SELECT "id", "title", "info", "active", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Things" AS "Thing";
```

There is no thing.name field, so there was nothning to display in ng-repeat.